# Probability (Please let me know if its correct)

Tags: probability

A bank deposit bag has 10 Solyndra checks, 10 GE and 10 Keystone checks.  What are the probabilities of randomly picking without replacement:

A Keystone check?

A Keystone check and a GE check?

A Keystone check, then a GE check, then a Solyndra check?

What I think:

A Keystone Check: 10/30 = 1/3

A Keystone Check and a GE Check: 1/3 * 10/29 = 10/87 (NOT SURE)

A Keystone Check, then a GE check, then a Solyndra check: 1/3 * 10/29 * 10/28 = 25/609 = .041

Please let me know if those are right or wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems clear that in the second question, **either order** qualifies. So you need to multiply your answer by $2$. The other two calculations are correct. (Using $\frac{1}{30}$ instead of $\frac{1}{3}$ would display the structure better. It can be useful to simplify only at the end.)

Alternately, there are $\dbinom{30}{2}$ equally likely ways to choose a set of $2$ cheques from $30$. Only $1$ of these ways qualifies, so the probability is $\dfrac{1}{\binom{30}{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

These are correct if you require that the checks be picked in the order given.  If for the second you would also accept picking the GE check first and the Keystone check second you would have to multiply by $2$ (and in the third case ...).  And a nit $\frac {25}{609} \ne 0.041$  It is approximately equal, but not equal.